# Insert data from Datagridview to Datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, insert

I am Capable of Inserting Data from DataGridView to Datatable using C#. But i am fail to Update the Data from Datagridview to datatable using c# windows application?

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= dgvSpplrfrm.Rows.Count-1;i++)
        {
            drLocal = dtLocalC.NewRow();
            drLocal["splr_Slno"] = dgvSpplrfrm.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
            drLocal["splr_Cntctnm"] = dgvSpplrfrm.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
            drLocal["splr_Cntctdesig"] = dgvSpplrfrm.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
            drLocal["splr_Cntctmoblno"] = dgvSpplrfrm.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
            drLocal["splr_Cntctemail"] = dgvSpplrfrm.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
            dtLocalC.Rows.Add(drLocal);
        }
```

Comment: have you added column to the datatable ?

Comment: from database columns should be added...,based on columns i want to insert and update data

Comment: i have posted my answer

Comment: @arshad it is not updating

Comment: it will not update the data... it will give you a `DataTable` which you were trying

Comment: i want to update the data..,

Comment: then you can use dataadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `DataTable` contains all the column which you want to copy. Be careful with `ColumnName` of `DataTable` as well as `DataGridView`. You can try this :

```
public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    DataTable dtLocalC = new DataTable();
    dtLocalC.Columns.Add("splr_Slno");
    dtLocalC.Columns.Add("splr_Cntctnm");
    dtLocalC.Columns.Add("splr_Cntctdesig");
    dtLocalC.Columns.Add("splr_Cntctmoblno");
    dtLocalC.Columns.Add("splr_Cntctemail");

    DataRow drLocal = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvSpplrfrm.Rows)
    {
        drLocal = dtLocalC.NewRow();
        drLocal["splr_Slno"] = dr.Cells["splr_Slno"].Value;
        drLocal["splr_Cntctnm"] = dr.Cells["splr_Cntctnm"].Value;
        drLocal["splr_Cntctdesig"] = dr.Cells["splr_Cntctdesig"].Value;
        drLocal["splr_Cntctmoblno"] = dr.Cells["splr_Cntctmoblno"].Value;
        drLocal["splr_Cntctemail"] = dr.Cells["splr_Cntctemail"].Value;
        dtLocalC.Rows.Add(drLocal);
    }

    return dtLocalC;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply u can do it like this:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
   return dgvSpplrfrm.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Binding the DataTable object to the DatagridView.

You can use a BindingSource to do this:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An article demonstrates how to fetch data from a GridView and how to store it into a DataTable.Have a look of below resource

[resource link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cd3aa3/fetch-data-from-gridview-and-store-into-datatable/)

Comment: i want in Windowsapplication

Comment: Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hw5ayeet.aspx) You need to perform cast on it.                      DataTable dtFromGrid = new DataTable();
            dtFromGrid = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

Answer (score 0):

I tried this..May be this one help you..

Step 1:

Drag a GridView onto the form and set it's AutoGenerateColumns property to False.

Use Template Fields to display GridView data. Design the GridView as per your reqirements.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShoppingCart" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                 EmptyDataText="There is nothing in your shopping cart." GridLines="None" 
                 Width="31%" CellPadding="5" ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="BookId" onrowdeleting="gvShoppingCart_RowDeleting"  
                  >  
                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#3D7169" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />  
                 <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="#6C6B66" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />  
                 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" />  
                 <Columns>  
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Iamge">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Image ID="BookImg" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BookImage") %>' runat="server" hight="15px" width="20px"/>

                      </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Name">  
                         <ItemTemplate>  
                             <asp:Label ID="lblBookName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BookName")%>'></asp:Label><br /> 
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">  
                         <ItemTemplate>  
                             <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Bookprice")%>'></asp:Label><br />  
                         </ItemTemplate>

                     </asp:TemplateField>  

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TXTQty" runat="server"  Text="1" Width="40px" onkeyup="CalculateTotals();"></asp:TextBox>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
                      <b>Total Amount:</b>
                  </FooterTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="LBLSubTotal" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="LBLTotal" runat="server" ForeColor="White" ></asp:Label>
                  </FooterTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Remove" ShowDeleteButton="True" />

                 </Columns>  
             </asp:GridView>
```

Here in Eval pass your table column name .

Step 2:

Use the following code to fetch data from a GridView and store it into a DataTable.

```
private void getGridInfo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("BookName", typeof(String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("BookQty", typeof(String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("BookImg", typeof(String)));

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvShoppingCart.Rows)
        {
            Image Bookimg = (Image)row.FindControl("BookImg");
            Label Booknames = (Label)row.FindControl("lblBookName");
            TextBox Bookqty = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TXTQty");
            Label TotalPrice = (Label)row.FindControl("LBLTotal");
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Booknames.Text;
            dr[1] = Bookqty.Text;
            dr[2] = Bookimg.ImageUrl.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        Session["QtyTable"] = dt;
        Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Step 3:

Here in dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("BookName", typeof(String))) you can write any header text for the column.

Call this function where you want to store a GridView data into a DataTable.